# Negative and positive percentage range

Tags: php

I want to get a percentage of the current value between -60 and 60.

so if

```
NUMBER == 60
```

The result should be 100%

```
NUMBER == -60
```

The result should be 0%

```
NUMBER == 0
```

The result should be 50%

How i can achieve this?

Comment: This is a simple math related question, why dont you solve it yourself using a calculater? 60 / 60=1 ,60 / -60=-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NUMBER + 60) / 1.2

Or 
(NUMBER + 60) / 120 / 100

Answer (score 2):

This is basic math

```
MIN = -60;
MAX = 60;
if (NUMBER < MIN) {
    PERCENT = 0;
}
else if (NUMBER > MAX) {
    PERCENT = 100;
}
else {
    PERCENT = (NUMBER-MIN)*100/(MAX-MIN);
}
```